# Read a db file with C# FormApp and ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net

I'm trying to read a simple sqlite db file (which I create with DB Browser) with c# form application ADO.NET.

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultC"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Seccessfull!");
    }
```

In App.config:

```
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultC" connectionString="ExamDB.db;Database=ExamDB;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Getting an error for this request.
Note that I save the db file in the bin/debug folder and the main root as well.

please your help

Comment: What's the error, what does your debugger say?

Answer (score 0):

You use sqlclient, but this is an db file, so you should use [Microsoft.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/5.0.11?_src=template) package.

Here is the modified code:

```
SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultC"].ToString();
con.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Connection Seccessfull!");
```

And the modified ConnectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultC" connectionString="Data Source=ExamDB.db" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a funddamental issue:

> sqlite db file

Yeah, get that, but then WHY...

> using System.Data.SqlClient;

That is the client (as per documentation) for MS SQL Server. OBVIOUSLY it will not work - different technology stack.

Use the Microsoft.Data.SqlLite package available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/5.0.11?_src=template